# htaccess redirect on fatal php error?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way to redirect to an /error.php page when a fatal php error occurs. I have htaccess setup to log errors, but how can I redirect on fatal error using htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) with a [shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to forward them on fatal error.

```
register_shutdown_function('forward_fatal');
function forward_fatal(){
    header("Location: error.php");
}
```

Comment: Note that for this to work, you either enable output buffering or guarantee that no output has been sent prior to the error.